# Multiple join query builder doctrine2

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

```
 public function search($params)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('auto');
        if (isset($params['manufacturer'])) {
            $qb->join('auto.manufacturer', 'man')
            ->where('man.manufacturer = :manufacturer')
            ->setParameter('manufacturer', $params['manufacturer']);
        }
        if (isset($params['model'])) {
            $qb->join('auto.model', 'mod')
                ->where('mod.model = :model')
                ->setParameter('model', $params['model']);
        }

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Query return error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens

Comment: Can you var_dump $params ?

Comment: array ()
  'manufacturer' => string 'Opel' (length=4)
  'model' => string '45' (length=2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `where` with `andWhere` function. For the reason that when you have 2 parameters, you replace first where condition with second where condition and in result you have 2 bound parameters with only one token.